# Enable debugging in design mode in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, debugging

Is there a way to enable debugging from within the Windows Forms Designer in Visual Studio (any version, up to and including Visual Studio 2010)?

What I mean is, say I have some custom user control, and this control has certain validation that it performs when I set a particular property. I'd like to be able to set a breakpoint somewhere within that code, and step through it to see what happens when I set the property from the designer.

Comment: are you talking design-time debugging, such as moving / resizing controls?,  or RUN-TIME, when the user interacts with the form and does something that actually changes the property value.

Comment: @DRapp: I'm talking about design-time debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, start another instance of Visual Studio.  It is described in [detail in this MSDN library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ytx0z24.aspx).